How to force `reftex-label` function to insert a more environment-dependent label?
By invoking reftex-label or by the hotkey C-c ( a label is automatically inserted in the document. For the section environment, the label is fine. But for an environment like theorem or thm a label like  \label{thm:pythagoras-theorem-1} or \label{theorem:pythagoras-theorem-1} is more suitable than \label{sec:pythagoras-theorem-1}. Can one customize reftex-label function to behave in that manner?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\section{Pythagoras' theorem}
\label{sec:pythagoras-theorem}

\begin{thm}\label{sec:pythagoras-theorem-1}
 In a right triangle, the square of the length of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the lengths of the other two sides
\end{thm}
\end{document}


You have to customize the variable reftex-label-alist.  This is an excerpt from the docstring:

reftex-label-alist is a variable defined in reftex-vars.el.
Alist with information on environments for \label-\ref use.
This doc string is easier to understand after reading the
configuration examples in the manual.  Looking at the builtin defaults
in the constant reftex-label-alist-builtin may also be instructive.
Set this variable to define additions and changes to the default.  The
only things you MUST NOT change is that ?s is the type indicator for
section labels, and SPC for the any label type.  These are
hard-coded at other places in the code.
The value of the variable must be a list of items.  Each item is a
list itself and has the following structure:
(ENV-OR-MACRO TYPE-KEY LABEL-PREFIX REFERENCE-FORMAT CONTEXT-METHOD
          (MAGIC-WORD ... ) TOC-LEVEL)

Each list entry describes either an environment carrying a counter for
use with \label and \ref, or a LaTeX macro defining a label as (or
inside) one of its arguments.  The elements of each list entry are: ...

In short, you probably want something like this in your init file:
(setq reftex-label-alist
      '(("theorem" ?T "thm:" "~ref{%s}"
         nil (regexp "[Th]heorems?") nil)))

I suggest you check the manual in order to understand the addition above.  Note that the ?t key is preset for tables, so the capital ?T.
